# How to use Callback function on successful HTTP request in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new to Angular2. I have referred the Hero Tutorial given in official web site and have written the following code for HTTP post request in Angular2 as per my requirement. I am used to java-script and i use AJAX calls to interact with web server, in javascript-AJAX call we can perform some function on successful AJAX call(callback function). How do i achieve that in angular2 ? i want to use Alerts also. On success/fail of each call show a Alert Box saying its Success or Failure.

```
@Injectable()
export class LicenceService {
constructor(private http: Http) {}
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
/* URL to web api*/
private licenceUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/***/****/installation/uploadLicense';  



sendData(key: string){
    return this.http
        .post(this.licenceUrl, key, this.headers)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
private static handleError (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
    return Promise.reject(error.json());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is already in your code

```
sendData(key: string){
    return this.http
        .post(this.licenceUrl, key, this.headers)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {
           res.json().data;
           // code here is executed on success
         })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

or for the caller

```
this.sendData(somekey).then(result => /*put after after success code here */);
```

Comment: Thank you.It was very helpful. I went in detail and read the Angular docs again and got my doubts clear. Services and HTTP section solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Although, Your question is already answered, Here is another approach which keeps Sevice and callback logic separate. I have achieved it with the use of **subscibe** and **Observable**

Here is my **question.compnent.ts**

```
    ngOnInit() {
               this.getQuestions();
    }        
    getQuestions() {
        this.yourService.getQuestions()
            .subscribe(
            data => this.displayData = data,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
            () => { 
                  //this gets called on completion, callback code comes here
                  } 
            );
    }
```

And my **question.service.ts** which takes care of HTTP requests part

```
   getQuestions(): Observable<DisplayData[]>{
      const endPoint = 'http://localhost:3000/yourApi';
      return this.http.get(endPoint).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

**Note**: this.displayData is a variable of type DisplayData[], which is used as an observable in Service.

Sorry for the long post. Cheers :)